# Is this really an invalid flag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548519/is-it-possible-to-select-just-an-attributes-value-from-xml-or-rss-using-yql/9548620#9548620) yesterday. Here's the contents of it for your inspection:

> What does this give you?
>
> ```
> SELECT current_conditions.temp_c.data FROM xml
>   WHERE url="http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Tbilisi"
>   AND itemPath="//weather/current_conditions/temp_c/@data"
> ```

Which should obviously be a comment, right? So I flagged it as NAA.

Looking at my flags, I noticed that it was declined with the standard 'a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it'.

Why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Could it be an answer posing as a rhetorical question?

Could editing it just to improve the code be a better idea than flagging it?

Comment: @George Stocker: I don't believe you. Flagged.

Comment: @BoltClock Can mods actually flag stuff?

Comment: @Undo: Yes, and technically we can handle our own flags too but we don't do that of course :)

Comment: @Boltclock's a Unicorn You mean I wasn't supposed to decline the flag on my answer? How can I exercise unlimited power if you keep limiting it with your rules?

Comment: @George: Why stop now?!

Comment: @GeorgeStocker real _unlimited_ power would be you to flag your own answer and decline your own flag on your own answer. After that, you could come to meta, ask a question challenging the "unfair decline", answer it with deepest apologies about the mistake, accept that answer...

Comment: @gnat: He can also put a bounty on it and award it to himself.*

Answer (score 2):

I'll occasionally put comments into answers if I believe it will be difficult to read as a comment.

IMO that would have made for pretty tough reading in a comment; that alone might have lead me to put it into an answer. That said, I would have made it clear that it was a comment but I needed formatting.

Caveat: I don't know enough about the subject under discussion to know if it was a comment, or an answer. *Whichever* it was, it should be clarified: if it's a comment, it should say as much, and if it's an answer, something regarding *why* it's an answer would be in order.

Comment: Putting comments into answers is probably a bad usage of answers! If you have a long comment, you could just split it up into two or three comments, or if you have a code example, you could place it on Pastebin or somewhere else and link to it.

Comment: @JonathonHobbs In some cases I agree, but making people chase down for lines of code is silly.

Answer (score 2):

How does this sound?

Nope, it is an answer albeit with a comment-esque tone. While I agree that the tone made it ambiguous as to whether it should a comment or an answer, the code does seem like an attempt to answer the question. So judging *as a whole*, it isn't really "Not an Answer".